# VisualStudio 2010 - PowerShell Add-In?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, powershell, add-in, powershell-2.0

Is there any PowerShell Add-Inn for VisualStudio 2010?
I only found the VS Command Shell Add-In for VS 2005 and 2008 (Add-In from 2007)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/), [PowerGUI VSX](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/), and [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3).

All three have a PowerShell console embedded in VS.

Comment: PowerGUI VSX has some caveats: eg. it does not fully support "Find Next". You can search your solution for a term, but when that term was found in an PowerGUI VSX tab it will not find any other matches in other files.

Answer (score 3):

I installed [Power Console](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/) from the extension manager.

Comment: I have tried the [powerconsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3) as well and it is pretty cool. I would also recommend installing [Productivity power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), which has useful extensions.

Comment: +1 thanks for the suggestion on Productivity Power Tools! I need to try that one out.

Comment: PowerConsole has been folded into NuGet as well, so I'd install NuGet if I were you.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell console is also part of NuGet.

Comment: Yes the Nuget Package Managemenet (PM) Console looks like the most obvious choice (and VS2012 have Nuget by default)

Answer (score 1):

[StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) is an interesting project; for manipulating Studio via PowerShell from within Studio.

Comment: Yes, StudioShell looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [PowerGUI](http://www.powergui.org/downloads.jspa), then right click on the `_.ps1` file from Visual Studio, click on "Open With...", and select PowerGUI.

[image]